# winfo_exists() does not see an existing Label

Tags: python, tkinter

I can't get Label.winfo_exists() to see a Label printed earlier.

I have a window with multiple buttons that all pass data to this routine. On the first pass, this prints Labels on "line A." if another button is pressed (including the first one) this routine runs again, printing the same set of labels on line "A" again, while printing the data from the second button press on line "B." I am trying to delete all previously laid labels before putting another layer down. I would actually have up to line "L" as a maximum.

So I run the routine. On the first pass, I get a NameError at the start (because that label is not there, yet). After I create the label, I do the test again and the winfo_exists() shows properly.

On the second pass, (I have tried the same and different buttons), the first check shows 0 from a NameError again, when it should show 1. After I print the label the second time, it shows 1 again and if I try to delete from another routine, it deletes the 2nd one on top, but not the original label.

This window has lots of other data that I can't just delete the whole window.

```
rosterloops = len(final_roster)
print(f'Roster Loops {rosterloops}')                # Prints 1 on 1st run, 2 on 2nd
ex_test = IntVar()
if rosterloops >=1:
    try:
        ex_test = roster_unit.winfo_exists()
    except NameError:
        print('NameError')                          # Prints on both runs
        ex_test = 0
    except KeyError:
        print('Key Error')
        ex_test = 0
    print(f'BV Test 1 is {ex_test}')                # Prints "0" on both runs
    if ex_test == 1:
        print('Got here!')                          # Never gets here
        roster_del.destroy()
    data = final_roster.get(1)
    data_split = data.split("@")
    org = data_split[0]
    name = data_split[1]
    model = data_split[2]
    gunnery = int(data_split[7])
    pilot = int(data_split[8])
    num1 = int(bva)
    num2 = float(gpmatrix[gunnery][pilot])
    roster_adj_bv = round((num1 * num2))
    bv_array[1] = roster_adj_bv

    # Name/Model
    roster_unit = Label(root, text=f' {name} {model}')
    roster_unit.place(x=rosterx + 40, y=rostery, width=230)
    # Gunnery/Pilot
    roster_gun = Label(root, text=f'{gunnery}    /')
    roster_gun.place(x=rosterx + 270, y=rostery)
    roster_gplus = Button(root, image=pimg, width=20, height=15,
                                          command=lambda rl=1, x=rosterx, y=rostery: upg(root, rl, final_roster,
                                                                                          bv_array, x, y))

    try:
        ex_test = roster_unit.winfo_exists()
    except NameError:
        print('NameError')
        ex_test = 0
    except KeyError:
        print('Key Error')
        ex_test = 0
    print(f'BV Test 1a is {ex_test}')                # Prints "1" on both runs
```

I should get the first winfo_exists() run to show a 0 on the 1st pass, then 1 on the second so the program can get to the .destroy() functions under the "Got here!" print.